# Delegation is nil , MVVM approach, two VC have the same VM. iOS, swift

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

There is a base class conforms to `ViewModelInsertProtocol` with the function `insertToCollection()`. The `delegate` is set to self in the `viewDidLoad` method of `CollectionViewController` class.

```
class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, ViewModelInsertProtocol {


func insertToCollection() {
    print("asdasd")
    collection.performBatchUpdates({
                     collection.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(row: viewModel.notes.count - 1, section: 0)])
                 }, completion: nil)
}


//MARK: -Variables

let reuseIdentifier = "cell"
var isEdit = false
var isSettingsEdit = false
var viewModel  = ViewModel()


//MARK: -OUTLETS

@IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var bacgroundImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var collection: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var sideViewConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var settingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var sideView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var icon: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var settingButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var backgr: UIButton!
//MARK: - LifeCycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    configureUI()
    viewModel.delegate = self
 }
```

If I want to add new UICollectionCell I have to go to another popVC 
PopVC and my Baseclass has instances of viewModel

var viewModel = ViewModel()
I use the same viewModel for both classes, Look at the SaveBtn here in PopVC, in this place I use delegate method.

```
var viewModel = ViewModel()


//MARK: -Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configure()
    addObservers()
    viewModel.popDelegate = self


}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    viewModel.editSelected = false
}

func configure() {
    saveBtnOutlet.visualButton()
    xBtnOutlet.visualButton()
    cancelBtnOutlet.visualButton()
    firstCardColor.visualButton()
    secondCardColor.visualButton()

}


   @IBAction func CancelBtn(_ sender: Any) {
       dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }

   @IBAction func saveBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    viewModel.saveData(text: textF.text)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

   }


rotocol ViewModelInsertProtocol: class {
func insertToCollection()
}

  extension ViewModel {

func numberOfRows() -> Int {
    return notes.count
}

}

class ViewModel {

var notes: Results<Model> {
    get{
        return realm.objects(Model.self)
    }
}
weak var delegate : ViewModelInsertProtocol? = nil
weak var popDelegate: PopDelegate? = nil
var backgroundImageIndex = 0
var editSelected = false
let realm = try! Realm()

var size = Sizes.largeSize
var background: String = "wood"

func saveData(text: String) {
    let newcard = Model()
    newcard.note = text
    RealmSerivce.shared.create(newcard)
    print(notes.count)
    if delegate == nil {print("nil")}
    delegate?.insertToCollection()

}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Beneath PopVC class I pasted viewModel class with protocol

Comment: Can you be more clear? I didn't get what you're asking.

Comment: ok.  I have two ViewCOntrollers, one VC is the base one the second is something like popUp. Both are connected to one ViewModel and have created their own instances of viewModel inside of these classes. If I want to add new Cell I need to click savBtn in PopVC which envoke method from ViewModel, this method create one object and then by the help of delegate method should insert new Cell in BaseClass . More clear?

Comment: Write protocol in POPVC and conform Baseclass that Protocol. Then u should be able to call back and get any data you want back from POPVC. In the function u can add new uicollectionView Cell Method.

Comment: Will be this correct with mvvm approach? Earlier I thought that my POPVC has to connect firstly with ViewModel and ViewModel will update then BaseClass.

Comment: your way works as I exptected

Answer (score 1):

Following MVVM approach and dependency injection you can inject your ViewModel instead of creating a new instance in your pop controller, so, for example, in the prepare for segue if you are using Storyboard:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "PopVcIdentifier" {
        let popController = segue.destination as? PopVC
        popController?.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}
```

Or in a showPopUp function:

```
func showPopUp() {
    let popController = PopVC()
    popController.viewModel = viewModel
    present(popController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: So in your approach we will have in two VC the same instance of viewModel correct? What is the difference for me to have the same instance and created two separate instance in every class? I give you plus because I did not know earlier this way of thinking.thx

Comment: The base controller viewModel's delegate was nil because you were calling the saveData function from a new instance of your viewModel class.

Answer (score 0):

I found two next problems in my app.
1. I try doing the same as in first problem , not to insert new cell but rather delete cell, and to achieve that I created protocol in PopVC , conform it in BaseClass and set delegate in prepareForSegueMethod. This works perfect for the first task. I mean for cellInsert but doesn't work for delete. The difference is that when I want to delete my cell I fo to the PopVC by the help of didSelectItemAtIndexPath , in the case of insertion I use plus button. Do I need to set delegation for cell in didSelectItemAtIndexPah ?

2 Problem with selection of cell: I can't select first cell in my collectionView, In didselectItemForIndePath I use method print(indexPath.row). The problem is that this print shows me wrong row. If I select second row for example , print shows me 1 or 3 row. one time it prints "1", another time "0" , another time "5" Do you know maybe what is going on here?